# Debian/Raspbian install QGIS 3.x

Tags: build, installation, package, debian, qgis

Re-posted from GIS stackexchange as this is becoming more of a software question.

I'm trying to install QGIS 3.x on Raspbian Stretch with Desktop.

I found this build-from-source [guide](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.github.com/qgis/QGIS/master/doc/INSTALL.html) using this [forum post](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=216187), but my linux-fu is weak.

I followed sections 3.5 and 3.6 of that guide, and then started on section 3.8.

At the `dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -b` stage, I get an "unmet build dependencies" error. When trying to `sudo apt-get install` the missing packages I get several "Unable to locate package" errors (`libqscintilla2-qt5-dev`, `qt3d-assimpsceneimport-plugin`, `qt3d-defaultgeometryloader-plugin`, and `qt3d-scene2d-plugin`).

I've already added `deb https://qgis.org/debian unstable main` and `deb-src https://qgis.org/debian unstable main` to my `sources.list` file (as per QGIS install [page](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html)...but now I'm stumped as to what to do.

Do I need to add another source (which one?) to that file, or is it something completely different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative to building from source.

**Issue**: with the QGIS install [instructions](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html) (assuming I followed them correctly) - it was unable to find the `python3-qgis` package.

**Solution:** basically use a different mirror than what the install recommends.

Starting from a fresh Raspbian Stretch with Desktop install.

Run: `sudo apt-get update`

Run: `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`

- Uncomment the `deb-src` line (not sure this matters).
- Add the following line: "`deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian sid main`" (alternative mirrors can be found [here](https://packages.debian.org/sid/armhf/qgis/download)).

Run: `sudo apt-get update`

Run: `sudo apt-get install qgis python3-qgis qgis-plugin-grass`

- This will install ~300 packages, and can take a while (~4min to download for me). After the download there is a changelog/notice that must be read (keep pressing return then q). Soon after starting the download there is a prompt...once you're past that you should be safe to step away while it installs.

Once done you can launch QGIS (3.4 Madeira LTR as of this writing) by simply typing `qgis` from the terminal.