# QGIS 3.x debian armhf install (RPi 4)

Tags: build, installation, package, debian, qgis

I'm trying to upgrade my RPi 3s with QGIS 3.4 LTR to RPi 4s. Starting from a fresh `Buster` install.

I followed my instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55682855/debian-raspbian-install-qgis-3-x), but I'm getting missing `python3-qgis` messages.

I've tried to manually install `qgis`, `qgis-plugin-grass` and `python3-qgis` by downloading the `.deb` files from [debian](https://packages.debian.org/sid/armhf/python3-qgis/download) and then calling

```
sudo dpkg -i /path/to/deb/file
sudo apt-get install -f
```

But it's not working either (it *seems* to install correctly) - trying to run `qgis` gets a command not found error.

Do I need to install those packages in a specific order? Is there a different mirror I should use or should I suppress default mirrors in `sources.list`? Alternatively, is there a QGIS directory I can copy from my old RPi3 SD card?

Comment: I also tried building from source - it seemed to be working, but the Pi froze after a while.

Comment: did you try to run the binary directly?

Comment: @renzop I didn't, the binaries I found at qgis.org/debian (or /debian-ltr) were only for `i386` and `amd64` - but I need `armhf`. Could they still work on `armhf`?

Comment: I meant the binaries on your raspberry after installing.  If the py "Froze" I suspect you have a thermal issue my pi4 get very hot... you need a heatsink. Especially when you do demanding tasks.

Comment: Gotcha, it never finished compiling from source. I have sinks and fan...seemed like an out of memory issue during compiling but I'll confirm that there are no binaries anywhere on there

Comment: Ah, voila. migth be a solution. In many tutorials etc. people disable swap on the rpi, to save the sd cards lifespan... but if you use too much memory, it will just crash. Seems like we have an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the comments:

1. Try to check if the compilation created binaries.
2. If they are not available, check why the Rpi crashed during compilation
3. migth be: heat problem (RPI 4 needs heatsinks, Power Supply most normal powersupply wont work properly whith RPI 4, or disabled swap etc.)